# Issue getting http.post to work in angular 4

Tags: php, json, angular, http

Code:

```
this.http.post<CommentData>(submitScript, {path:path, author:authorInput, comment:commentInput}).subscribe (
        data => {
            let json:CommentData = {path:path, author:authorInput, comment:commentInput};
            data = json;
        },
        err => {
            console.log("Error: Post failed");
        }
    );
```

So, the purpose is to post the path, authorinput and commentinput to the php handler file to dump into the database. The problem i'm having is that just hits the error block. So I am assuming that i'm doing something wrong with the way the data is being fed in or processed, but I have no idea what

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the issue is?

Comment: What errors are you getting and from where?

Comment: Which HTTP  response code is given for the POST request? You can see that one in the browsers developer network pane tracking all requests - highly recommended for trouble shooting HTTP requests w/ the browser.

Comment: The error i'm getting is this:

    image1.jpg 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\kreativecoating.com\httpdocs\commentDataPostHandler.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\kreativecoating.com\httpdocs\commentDataPostHandler.php on line 37

Which  refers to the statement itself:

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tblcomments (imgpath,author,comment) VALUES (?,?,?)");


So the image is there and the other 2 are null for some reason, so the data isn't going through for the other 2 via the http post

Comment: You should show the backend code (how is data extracted from request)

Comment: That's a backend issue as you said on your comment, so the question is completely wrong. Did you tried to read the php error? They aren't monsters! They're smart and tell us what happens!!! "Call .. function prepare on *null*". You posted the code. You are trying to call prepare on the `$mysqli` variable that's empty. Read your code and find why that variable is empty.

Comment: Ok. Well it seems to be dying on the prepare statement, which looks like this:

    // Set up the sql command
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tblcomments (imgpath,author,comment) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        // Bind the data
        $stmt->bind_param('imgpath', $imagePath);
        $stmt->bind_param('author', $author);
        $stmt->bind_param('comment', $comment);
        // Execute the sql
        $stmt->execute();
        // Close the statement
        $stmt->close();

Comment: I know that, I read the php error, i'm aware of what its doing, the thing is it shouldn't be. The values aren't null, and I know that because i'm outputting them as test data in the php file before I use them, it has to be something to do with the values part of the statement, but in php, ?'s are what you use to set them, right?